# Resolve HostName from CNAME in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a network wherein CNAME entries are created for some servers and not for others. How can I get the details for server names alone by executing `Resolve-DnsName` script?

If I try

```
$servername = Resolve-DnsName -Name webserver.999.com
Write-Host $servername.Name
```

I get 2 results one with webserver.999.com and another with the actual server name post resolving the DNS for servers with CNAME, but only the server name where CNAME entry is not present. I am looking for a solution wherein the command catches the result with only the server name.

Comment: By "host name" do you mean the SMB Windows machine name?

Comment: Yes, actual name of the server to which the CNAME points at

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the result that is an A record:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name foo.example.com |
    Where-Object { $_.QueryType -eq 'A' } |
    Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Comment: I was going to suggest`Resolve-DnsName -Type A ...` instead of `Resolve-DnsName ... | Where-Object Type -eq A`, but it seems that the former sometimes reports _additional_ records of a different type; e.g., `(Resolve-DnsName www.microsoft.com -Type A).Type` Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @mklement0 Nothing definitive. However, the call needs to resolve the entire chain of CNAMEs to get to the underlying A record, so I can see why it returns multiple results. After all, just responding that "www.microsoft.com" isn't an A record wouldn't be too useful from a name resolution perspective. It would make sense from a DNS management perspective, but there's a different set of cmdlets for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense; another thing that's perhaps of interest: it seems that such an _indirect_ lookup of an `A` record only ever outputs _one_ (as the last), whereas querying a name that directly has an `A` record can result in _multiple_ `A` records for large sites (e.g., `Resolve-DnsName microsoft.com -Type A`).

Answer (score 2):

To turn a CNAME into the original hostname:

```
Resolve-DnsName 'webserver.999.com' -Type CNAME |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'NameHost'
```

Comment: This is not working if "webserver.999.com" doesn't have CNAME and "webserver.999.com" is the actual computer name

Answer (score 0):

One more way, which returns original hostname for a CNAME, original A name or just additional A name with the same IP of the server, as long as PTR records are maintained properly and point to the original hostname.

```
(resolve-dnsname (resolve-dnsname webserver.999.com).ipaddress ptr).namehost
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell code to read CNAME records from a text file and output the original hostnames to another text file. Here's a script to do that:

```
# Specify the input and output file paths
$inputFilePath = "CNAMEs.txt"
$outputFilePath = "OriginalHostnames.txt"

# Read CNAMEs from the input file
$cnames = Get-Content -Path $inputFilePath

# Initialize an array to store the original hostnames
$originalHostnames = @()

# Iterate through each CNAME and resolve it to get the original hostname
foreach ($cname in $cnames) {
    $originalHostname = (Resolve-DnsName (Resolve-DnsName $cname).IPAddress PTR).NameHost
    $originalHostnames += $originalHostname
}

# Write the original hostnames to the output file
$originalHostnames | Out-File -FilePath $outputFilePath

# Display a message indicating the task is complete
Write-Host "Original hostnames have been written to $outputFilePath"
```